# The webscraper keeps looping and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is the code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

home_url = "http://books.toscrape.com/index.html"
base_url = "http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/{}_{}/index.html"
page_url_format = "http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/{}_{}/page-{}.html"

response = requests.get(home_url)
response.encoding = response.apparent_encoding

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
list_of_genre = []
ul_element = soup.find("ul", class_="nav nav-list")
genres = ul_element.find_all("a")
list_genres = []
main_genres = []

for genre in genres:
    text = genre.text.strip()
    list_genres.append(text)
del list_genres[0]

for i in list_genres:
    i = i.replace(" ", "-").lower()
    main_genres.append(i)

with open("genre.txt", "w") as file:
    for genre in main_genres:
        index_number = 2  # Initialize index number for each genre
        page_number = 1  # Initialize page number for each genre
        while True:
            page_url = page_url_format.format(genre, index_number, page_number)
            response_page = requests.get(page_url)
            response_page.encoding = response_page.apparent_encoding
            
            if response_page.status_code == 200:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response_page.text, "lxml")
                books = soup.find_all("li", class_="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3")
            else:
                url = base_url.format(genre, index_number)
                response_index = requests.get(url)
                response_index.encoding = response_index.apparent_encoding
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response_index.text, "lxml")
                books = soup.find_all("li", class_="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3")

            if not books:
                break

            for book in books:
                cost_element = book.find("p", class_="price_color")
                cost = cost_element.text

                h3_tag = book.find("h3")
                title_element = h3_tag.find("a")
                title = title_element["title"]

                stock_availability_element = book.find("p", class_="instock availability")
                stock_availability = stock_availability_element.text

                class_star = book.find("p", class_=True)
                p_class = class_star["class"]
                star_name_list = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
                for i in star_name_list:
                    if i == p_class[1]:
                        stars = i
                        break

                file.write(f"Title: {title}\n")
                file.write(f"Price: {cost.strip()}\n")
                file.write(f"Stock Availability: {stock_availability.strip()}\n")
                file.write(f"Stars: {stars}\n")
                file.write("\n")

            page_number += 1
        else:
            index_number += 1  # Increment index number for the next genrepe here
```

This is the code which has as seen a for loop with the genres taken from the website, and if you're wondering I double checked the genres and they're correct so there is no problem with the list itself. The index number is 2, since the first genre is books which is just all the books the website has. The page url has to go through first since if there are multiple pages then the title and page number should be enough, if there is one page then the index and title is required, + the url should change. Also this is my first question, anyways one more thing, I know this code is wrong since the original webscraper produces 5000 thousand lines corresponding to 1000 thousand books, but this code produces legit over 40 thousand and i have to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using While True. This is referred to as an infinite loop because this condition can never be False therefor the loop will never end. You need a condition to exit the loop either in the while definition or some condition in the body of the loop where you call break to exit.